# Using VSCode .ipynb file: Is there a shortcut (keybinding) to collapse notebook sections (not cells)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I was wondering if there is a way to collapse all VSCode Jupyter notebook sections? Is there a command or a way to make one, or a setting one could toggle so that this happens by default?

I have looked around for a solution but have not been able to find any solution. Note: I am not asking about folding/collapsing cells but sections that one can create using the Markdown cells.

--

Thank you!